# Convert Python object to compatible type annotation

Tags: python

Say I have an arbitrary object, e.g.,:

```py
{3: ["a", "b"], 4: ["c", "d"], 5: ["e", "f"]}
```

or

```py
[np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6])]
```

Is there a nice way of converting these to a compatible (yet hopefully specific) type annotations such as `Dict[int, List[str]]` and `List[numpy.ndarray]` (respectively).

Comment: Not in standard Python.

Comment: `Dict[int, List[str]]` seems correct, what's the issue?

Comment: @SirajAlam: To detect and return `Dict[int, List[str]]`.

Comment: Implicit type checking works fine with my case. Such as [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkA5C.png)

Comment: @SirajAlam: Cool, but I would like to do this programmatically.